# Adding wordpress tags to content

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to add Wordpress tags to any content created on an Elementor page.

I was able to add this code below to my functions.php to allow tags on pages but now I need to be able to add tags to the content on the page (links,text blocks,sections, images,etc...).

```
// adding tags to pages
add_action( 'init', 'adding_tags_to_pages' );

function adding_tags_to_pages() 
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you have assigned tags on some of your pages and now in Elementor you want to display those assigned tags on page content if they are available on the current page?

Comment: @Vijay Hardaha Yes, that is correct!

Comment: I am not using **Elementor** for a long time but if I remember correctly. You can search for the **Post Info** Widget then add new items, choose type **terms** then from the next dropdown choose **tags** then set other settings, and you should have your tags on the page.

Comment: @Vijay Hardaha that works. But need to be able to assign tag to individual content sections. If I have an **image section** or a ***link box*** I want to be able to assign one of those tags to that content.

Comment: I don't think there is any default mechanism to do that.